# Jquery show() function not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code that works well in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE8 or, I'm assuming, versions lower than 8.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      $('div.hidden').hide();
      $('input.show:checked').each(function() {
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
      $('input.show').click(function() {
            $('div.hidden').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
});
</script>
```

At first I thought it may be due to the `:checked` selector, so I changed my code to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      $('div.hidden').hide();
      $('input.checked').each(function() {
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
      $('input.show').click(function() {
            $('div.hidden').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
      $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked", this.checked);
      });
});
</script>
```

No luck, so then I tried using IE9.js and then IE8.js, both with no effect. After that, I went back to fooling around with the selectors and tried swapping this:

```
$('input.checked').each(function() {
```

With this:

```
$('input[checked="checked"]').each(function() {
```

Again, I came up empty handed, so now I'm starting to think it may not be the selector. I've searched here and of course Google but haven't been able to come up with anything. Can anyone tell me why my code isn't working in IE8? Here is a JSFiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/bP4Uf/

Thank you!

Comment: are you using any other lib than jquery

Comment: Do you see any JS errors?

Comment: Does fiddle even work in IE8?

Comment: No other libraries, no errors and the fiddle did not work in IE8. The issue was my checkboxes having display:none set. thirtydot's answer below solved my problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checkboxes have `display: none`. That seems to be why it doesn't work in IE8.

One possible fix is to bind your click event directly to the label instead, for example:

```js
$('.show_label').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).find('input');
    $('div.hidden').hide();
    $('#' + $input.val()).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/bP4Uf/5/

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jQuery are you using? From the [website](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/):

> You asked for it, you got it: jQuery 2.0 has arrived! As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8 browsers.

You need to use version 1.x to get support for IE8 and lower.

Comment: 1.7.2. See the fiddle linked to in the question.